# Endeca connection String

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle, endeca

I need to configure and develop a small application using Oracle Endeca and .net language.

Currently trying to know that when we run these two batch files:

1. load_baseline_test_data.bat
2. baseline_update.bat

How endeca find the connection string.
Furthermore how endeca know the procedure name which specify the procedure name. which returns XML to endeca

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'connection string'. The two scripts you mention is all about building up an index while a 'connection string' implies that you are trying to extract the data.

Comment: Need to create a XML file which created by endeca on running this first command. But not know from where the database name identified to endeca

Comment: I'm still not understanding your question 100% but what I think you mean is that you want to know, how do you configure Endeca to extract data from your sql-server database via JDBC? The answer to that question can be found in chapter 13 for the [CAS Developer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38681_01/CAS.311/pdf/CASDevGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically endeca-server Url, here treated as connection string

eg.

```
http://domain_name.com:7001/endeca-server
```

Comment: Note to others commenting - this isn't a link to the solution, it is actually *part of* the solution, which happens to be a URL.